# Continuation to other rows when copying selected cells

Tags: vba

I have a spreadsheet with 500 lines (rows) I am using VBA below to move information from one sheet to other sheets, however it is only updating a specified raw ""5 not other rows (e.g rows 6 to 500) any one help with one that can have a continual VBA. I have four worksheet (Health RA, Task RA, Environment RA, Non-process RA) that this information should be distributed to.  At present this infor is only distributed to A5 not to A6..... according to the selection made.

```
Private Sub Decisionbtn_Click()
If Sheets("Baseline_RA").Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 14).Value = _
                                                 "Health risk assessment" Then
    Sheets("Health RA").Range("A5").Value = Sheets("Baseline_RA").Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1)
    Sheets("Health RA").Range("B5").Value = Sheets("Baseline_RA").Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2)
    Sheets("Health RA").Range("I5").Value = Sheets("Baseline_RA").Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 8)
    Sheets("Health RA").Range("O5").Value = Sheets("Baseline_RA").Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 11)
    Sheets("Health RA").Range("P5").Value = Sheets("Baseline_RA").Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 12)
    Sheets("Health RA").Range("Q5").Value = Sheets("Baseline_RA").Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 13)

    ElseIf Sheets("Baseline_RA").Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 14).Value = _
                                                 "Task risk assessment" Then
    Sheets("Task RA").Range("A5").Value = Sheets("Baseline_RA").Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1)
    Sheets("Task RA").Range("B5").Value = Sheets("Baseline_RA").Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2)
    Sheets("Task RA").Range("J5").Value = Sheets("Baseline_RA").Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 8)
    Sheets("Task RA").Range("P5").Value = Sheets("Baseline_RA").Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 11)
    Sheets("Task RA").Range("Q5").Value = Sheets("Baseline_RA").Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 12)
    Sheets("Task RA").Range("R5").Value = Sheets("Baseline_RA").Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 13)

    ElseIf Sheets("Baseline_RA").Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 14).Value = _
                                                  "Environment risk assessment" Then
    Sheets("Environment RA").Range("A5").Value = Sheets("Baseline_RA").Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1)
    Sheets("Environment RA").Range("B5").Value = Sheets("Baseline_RA").Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2)
    Sheets("Environment RA").Range("H5").Value = Sheets("Baseline_RA").Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 8)
    Sheets("Environment RA").Range("N5").Value = Sheets("Baseline_RA").Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 11)
    Sheets("Environment RA").Range("O5").Value = Sheets("Baseline_RA").Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 12)
    Sheets("Environment RA").Range("P5").Value = Sheets("Baseline_RA").Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 13)

    ElseIf Sheets("Baseline_RA").Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 14).Value = _
                                                  "Non-Process risk assessment" Then
    Sheets("Non-Process RA").Range("A5").Value = Sheets("Baseline_RA").Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1)
    Sheets("Non-Process RA").Range("B5").Value = Sheets("Baseline_RA").Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2)
    Sheets("Non-Process RA").Range("H5").Value = Sheets("Baseline_RA").Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 8)
    Sheets("Non-Process RA").Range("N5").Value = Sheets("Baseline_RA").Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 11)
    Sheets("Non-Process RA").Range("O5").Value = Sheets("Baseline_RA").Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 12)
    Sheets("Non-Process RA").Range("P5").Value = Sheets("Baseline_RA").Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 13)
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested but something like this should work

```
Private Sub Decisionbtn_Click()

    Dim shtDest As Worksheet, v As String, r As Range
    Dim rw As Range
    Dim rwStart As Long

    For Each r In Selection.Rows

        Debug.Print r.Row

        Set rw = r.EntireRow
        v = rw.Cells(14).Value

        Select Case v
            Case "Health risk assessment"
                Set shtDest = Sheets("Health RA")
            Case "Task risk assessment"
                Set shtDest = Sheets("Task RA")
            Case "Environment risk assessment"
                Set shtDest = Sheets("Environment RA")
            Case "Non-Process risk assessment"
                Set shtDest = Sheets("Health RA")
        End Select

        If shtDest Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'or warn user?

        'Find next empty row (assuming every sheet will have a value in ColA
        '  if a row is populated) and copy values over
        With shtDest.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
            .Cells(1, "A").Value = rw.Cells(1).Value
            .Cells(1, "B").Value = rw.Cells(2).Value
            .Cells(1, "I").Value = rw.Cells(8).Value
            .Cells(1, "O").Value = rw.Cells(11).Value
            .Cells(1, "P").Value = rw.Cells(12).Value
            .Cells(1, "Q").Value = rw.Cells(13).Value
        End With

   Next r


End Sub
```

Comment: Good to hear.  Your code will be easier to develop and maintain if you use some variables...